# $H^n(X, S)$ and $\check {H^n}(X,S)$ when $X\setminus S$ is an $n$-manifold (Hawaiian earring related)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I am dealing with a *compact* topological space $X$, such that $X\setminus S $ is an $n$-manifold, here $S\subset X$ is a *compact* subset  of $X$ ($S$ stands for singular locus).

An example could be the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) where $n=1$ and the singular locus can be taken to be the origin.

> Now, I would like to understand the relation between the top Cech cohomology and singular homology of the pair $\check {H^n}(X, S)$, $H^n(X, S)$.

> In particular I expect that $\check {H^n}(X, S)= H_c^n(X\setminus S)$ (cohomology with compact support) and that the latter is generated by the connected components of $X\setminus S$, is this correct? How to prove it?

> What about the singular cohomology $H^n(X,S)$ ? Is it isomorphic to $\check {H^n}(X, S)$?

Comment: Hmm, how do you define relative Cech cohomology?

Comment: @Thorgott an open covering $\mathcal U$ of $X$ defines an open covering of $S$ by taking intersections, $\mathcal U \cap S$, then we define
$\check {H}^*(X, S) = \lim_{\to} H_{simplicial}^*(N(\mathcal U), N(\mathcal {U}\cap S))$ by taking the direct limit over open covers, here $N(\mathcal U)$ is the nerve of the covering.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you. 3 questions:1) in the link you posted there is no mention to Cech cohomology, so how do you recover it from the $\pi_1$? 
2) So in general do we get that $\check H^n(X,S)\simeq \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A}\mathbb Z \langle \alpha \rangle $ where $A$ is the set of connected components of $X\setminus S$?
3) What about the singular cohomology of the pair?

Comment: Moreover, it is clear to me that for the Hawaiian earring the ordinary cohomology $H^1(X\setminus S) \simeq \Pi_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ but why also the compactly supported one is like that as you claim?

Comment: In general, $H_c^n(X\setminus S)$ is a product of $\mathbb{Z}$s with one factor for each orientable component of $X\setminus S$ (by coproducts turning into products, it suffices to verify this for connected $X\setminus S$ - the orientable case is Poincaré duality and the non-orientable one follows by a standard comparison with the oriented double cover). If $X$ is locally compact and $S$ a deformation retract of a neighborhood, you will have $H_c^n(X\setminus S)=H^n(X/S,S/S)=H^n(X,S)$, the point being that $X/S$ is a one-point compactification of $X\setminus S$.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, but on a second thought, in the Hawaiian earring, $X\setminus S$ has not the discrete topology (otherwise when we  compactify we would get that the Hawaiian earring is the infinite wedge of circles which is not) , so it is not a coproduct of real lines $\mathbb{R}$ and thus the $H^1_c$ should not be the infinite product.

Comment: The topology on $X\setminus S$ is certainly not discrete, but it is a coproduct of countably many real lines. The Hawaiian earring is indeed the one-point compactification of countably many disjoint intervals. The infinite wedge of circles, on the other hand, is not even compact. In the infinite wedge of circles, take the point opposite to the wedge point in each circle; these form an infinite sequence without convergent subsequence. Meanwhile, if you do the same thing in the Hawaiian earring, that sequence converges to the origin.

Comment: @Thorgott, right, but if we call $C := \bigsqcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}\times \{i\}$ the coproduct. Then $\mathbb{R}\times \{i\}$ and  $\mathbb{R}\times \{j\}$  can be separated with two open sets, while in it seems to me that in $X\setminus C$, this does not happen.

Comment: [in the above comment in the last line is $X\setminus S$ not $C$]

Also if I try to compute $H_c^1(X\setminus S)$ as $\mathrm {colim}_{K}H^1(X\setminus S, X\setminus S\setminus K)$, varying on $K$ compact  then I can choose as compacta the complement of decreasing balls centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $X\setminus S\setminus K$ will contain all but a finite number of intervals. 
Therefore $H^1(X\setminus S, X\setminus S\setminus K_n)\simeq \bigoplus_{i=}^n \mathbb Z$ and taking the colimit I get the direct sum (not direct product). 
Is this correct?

Comment: You can separate two distinct circles in the Hawaiian earring just fine once the origin has been removed. Perhaps try drawing a picture. As for the second point, you're right and I apologize for the mistake. Compactly supported cohomology turns coproducts into direct sums, not products, which I mixed up. The point is that you can only be compactly supported in a disjoint union if you meet only finitely many summands to begin with, so the compactly supported cochain complex is a colimit over the direct products on finitely many indices, which is the direct sum.

Comment: I see, this was a fruitful conversation, you deserve some points for it, feel free to post an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the worked out example of the Hawaiian earring. I'm afraid I don't have much to say about the general case, because the relative Cech cohomology groups seems very badly behaved formally. However, this is too long to leave as another comment.

To set this up, let $C_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be the circle of radius $1/n$ about $(0,1/n)$, so that $X=\bigcup_{n\ge1}C_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is the earring space and $S=\{(0,0)\}\subseteq X$ is the bad point. The complement $X\setminus S$ is homeomorphic to $\coprod_{n\ge1}\mathbb{R}$, a $1$-manifold.

The relative cohomology group $H^1(X,S)$ is canonically isomorphic to $H^1(X)$ via pullback $H^1(X,S)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}H^1(X)$, since $S$ is a singleton (this follows from the LES of the pair $(X,S)$), which is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{n\ge1}\mathbb{Z}$, see [here](https://wildtopology.com/2014/05/16/the-hawaiian-earring-group-is-not-free-part-ii/).

In general, if $Y=\coprod_{i\in I}Y_i$ is a coproduct of topological spaces, there is a natural isomorphism between the cochain complexes $C^{\bullet}(Y)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\prod_{i\in I}C^{\bullet}(Y_i)$, which is given by pullback along $Y_i\subseteq Y$ in each factor. In this way, the support of a cochain on $Y$ corresponds to the disjoint union of the supports of the restricted cochains on the $Y_i,\,i\in I$. A disjoint union of sets is compact if and only it is finite and each summand is compact, so this isomorphism identifies the compactly supported cochain complexes $C_c^{\bullet}(Y)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\bigoplus_{i\in I}C_c^{\bullet}(Y_i)$. On cohomology, this yields canonical isomorphisms $H_c^k(Y)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\bigoplus_{i\in I}H_c^k(Y_i)$ for all $k\ge0$. In the example, applying this observation to $X\setminus S\cong\coprod_{n\ge1}\mathbb{R}$, we obtain $H_c^1(X\setminus S)\cong\bigoplus_{n\ge1}H_c^1(\mathbb{R})\cong\bigoplus_{n\ge1}\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $X$ be any topological space and $S\subseteq X$ a singleton. For each open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, there is a natural pullback $H^k(N(\mathcal{U}),N(\mathcal{U}\vert_S))\rightarrow H^k(N(\mathcal{U}))$ for all $k\ge0$, which is an isomorphism for $k>0$ by the corresponding LES in cohomology. Taking the limit, we obtain an isomorphism $\check{H}^k(X,S)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}\check{H}^k(X)$.

Now let $X$ be the earring space again. For each $i\ge1$, let $\mathcal{U}_i$ be the cover of $X$ that consists of the following open sets:

- the union of $\bigcup_{n\ge i+1}C_n$ and arcs of diameter $<1/i$ about $(0,0)$ in each $C_n$ for $n=1,\dotsc,i$,
- arcs of diameter $<1/i$ in each $C_n$ for $n=1,\dotsc,i$, such that for each $n\in\{1,\dotsc,i\}$, the collection of all arcs in $C_n$ considered here together with the single arc contained in the previously mentioned open set form an open cover of $C_n$, where each arc intersects exactly two adjacent ones.

This part is a bit handwavy, but I don't wanna be more explicit. It's not hard to see pictorially that these choices are easily arrangeable in a way such that $\mathcal{U}_{i+1}$ refines $\mathcal{U}_i$ for all $i\ge1$. Furthermore, each open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is refined by $\mathcal{U}_i$ for $i\gg0$, as a consequence of the Lebesgue number lemma (note that the unions $\bigcup_{n\ge i+1}C_n$ have diameter shrinking to $0$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$). This implies the directed system of the $\mathcal{U}_i,\,i\ge0$ is cofinal in the directed system of all open covers of $X$, whence we can compute $\check{H}^1(X)\cong\varinjlim H^1(N(\mathcal{U}_i))$.

However, and I defer to the pictorial intuition again, it is by construction that $N(\mathcal{U}_i)\cong\bigvee_{n=1}^iS^1$ (here, it is relevant that we chose to avoid triple and higher intersections), and the refinments induce simplicial maps which realize the canonical projections $\bigvee_{n=1}^{i+1}S^1\rightarrow\bigvee_{n=1}^iS^1$ collapsing the $i+1$-th $S^1$ to the wedge point for all $i\ge1$. On cohomology, this corresponds to the canonical inclusion in the $i+1$-th summand $\bigoplus_{n=1}^i\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\bigoplus_{n=1}^{i+1}\mathbb{Z}$. In total, $\check{H}^1(X)\cong\varinjlim H^1(\bigvee_{n=1}^iS^1)\cong\varinjlim\bigoplus_{n=1}^i\mathbb{Z}=\bigoplus_{n\ge1}\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Cech cohomology groups can be defined for very general pairs $(X,A)$, but best results are obtained for compact (including Hausdorff!) pairs. This completely suffices for your question.

Cech cohomology has a number of interesting properties.

1. For compact polyhedral pairs (or more generally compact CW pairs) it agrees with singular cohomology.
2. Continuity: If $(X,A)$ is the inverse limit of an inverse system $(\mathbf X, \mathbf A)$ of compact pairs $(X_\alpha,A_\alpha)$, i.e. $(X,A) = \varprojlim (\mathbf X, \mathbf A)$, then $\check H^*(X,A)$ is the direct limit of Cech cohomology groups $\varinjlim \check H^*(\mathbf X, \mathbf A)$.
3. Strong excision: $\check H^*(X,A) = \check H^*(X/A,*)$. The latter is the reduced Cech cohomology of the quotient $X/A$.

The Hawaiian earring is the inverse limit of an inverse sequence $X_n= $ wedge of $n$ copies $S^1_i$ of the circle. The bonding maps $p_n : X_{n} \to X_{n-1}$ are the retractions mapping $S^1_n$ to the basepoint. Using 1. and 2.  we get

$$\check H^1(X,S) = \check H^1(X) = \Sigma = \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z .$$

The first singular cohomology group of the Hawaiian earring is also  $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$. To see this, we can use the exact universal cooeficient sequence
$$0 \to Ext(H_{n−1}(X),\mathbb Z) \to H^n(X) \to  Hom(H_n(X),\mathbb Z) \to 0$$
For $n =1$ we have $H_0(X) = 0$, thus
$$H^1(X) \approx Hom(H_1(X),\mathbb Z).$$

The first singular homology group of the Hawaiian earring has the form $\Pi \oplus (\Pi/\Sigma)$, where $\Pi = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$ is the  Baer-Specker-group (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)). By the way, the first Cech *homology* group is $\Pi$. We therefore get
$$H^1(X) \approx Hom(\Pi,\mathbb Z) \oplus Hom(\Pi/\Sigma,\mathbb Z) .$$
The first summand is isomorphic to $\Sigma$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baer%E2%80%93Specker_group)). The second summand can be identified with the subgroup of $Hom(\Pi,\mathbb Z)$ annihalating $\Sigma$. It is therefore a free Abelian group of (at most) countably infinite rank.

Here is an example where you can see that in general you cannot expect $\check H^n(X,S) = H^n(X,S)$ in the top dimension.

Let $X = S^2$ and $S = W$ be a copy of the [Warsaw circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_theory_(mathematics)). The singular cohomology of $W$ is trivial in all positive dimensions, its Cech cohomology agrees with that of $S^1$. Considering the long exact cohomology sequences of the pair $(S^2,W)$ we get
$$ 0 = H^1(W) \to H^2(S^2,W) \to H^2(S^2) = \mathbb Z \to H^2(W) = 0 ,$$
i.e. $H^2(S^2,W) = \mathbb Z$, and
$$ 0 = \check H^1(S^2) \to \check H^1(W) = \mathbb Z \to \check H^2(S^2,W) \to \check H^2(S^2) = \mathbb Z \to \check H^2(W) = 0 .$$
This short exact sequence splits and we get $\check H^2(S^2,W) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, a few questions: why the reduced Cech cohomology does not have a tilde over it? Does the usual excision hold for Cech cohomology? I have read in wikipedia that for Alexander-Spanier cohomology in order to perform excision we need a triple where $U\subset A\subset X$ with $U$ open (while in singular cohomology we do not need $U$ to be open).

Comment: It seems to me that the strong excision implies that
$\check {H^*}(X,S)\simeq \check{H^*}(X/S, *) \simeq  \check{H^*}((X\setminus S)^+, *)$ (one point compactification). Therefore if we assume that  $S$ is a deformation retract of one of its  neighbourhoods the latter is $H^*_c(X\setminus S)$.
But also under  the same assumption, an application of  excision and the long exact sequence of the triple shows that $H^*_c(X\setminus S) \simeq H^*(X, S)$ (singular cohomology).
Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't introduce a symbol for the reduced Cech cohomology of a space, but we could of course use the tilde. In general we have $h(X,\{x_0\}) \approx \tilde h(X)$ for each homology or cohomology functor $h$ (dimension irrelevant). For Cech and singular cohomology the reduced and unreduced groups only differ in dimension $0$. Strong excision implies usual excision (that's why it is called "strong"). That the strong excision axiom is satisfied is a non-trivial feature of Cech cohomology. Singular cohomology does not satisfy it. Alexander-Spanier cohomology satisfies the usual excision axiom.

Comment: @ Thank you Paul I have finally understood the role of that point. 

But why in Wikipedia and also in Spanier's book excision for Alexander-Spanier cohomology requires $U\subset A\subset X$ with $U$ open?
This is a stronger hypothesis than usual excision in, say, singular (co)homology.


Another curiosity:  for (possibly noncompact) manifolds do Alexander-Spanier and Singular cohomology with compact support coincide? Is there a set of axioms to see this ? What about infinite dimensional manifods?

Comment: Many questions! Do not ask them in form of comments, ask them officially.

Comment: I will thank you again

Comment: What exactly is your argument that $H^1(X)$ is not $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$? This is true as far as I know, see [here](https://wildtopology.com/2014/05/16/the-hawaiian-earring-group-is-not-free-part-ii/) for example. There also should be direct algebraic arguments that the dual of the Baer-Specker group is free of countable rank (in a natural way, from which it follows that the dual of the other summand of $H_1(X)$ is trivial), though they escape me right now.

Comment: @Thorgott You are right, thank you for your comment. I erroneously believed that the dual of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$ is again $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z$. I edited my answer.